# Populate html table column with database values

Tags: jquery, html

I need to populate table from the data fetched from database .How can i go for it in the script part .Need suggestion or solution

```
    <table border="0" style="margin-left:2%; margin-top:2%; ">
            <tr>
            <td align="left">ProductCode</td><td id="productcode"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Materialcontent</td><td id="materialcontent"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

Comment: You'll need some sort of server-side component to fetch the data from the database, either at page load or using AJAX

Comment: thnxs for replying , so can i put the content being fetched by ajax and use " table id " to put inside the table .

Answer (score 0):

Read [this (jQuery datatable)](http://britseyeview.com/software/dtgs/) and then [this (population via AJAX)](http://britseyeview.com/software/dtgs/poptable.html).